# Trouble converting string into List<int>

Tags: c#

I have a string that looks like "34,45,74,23" and is dynamically generated. How do I convert this into a List?

```
var y = numString();
y.ToList();
```

Comment: would that be the numbers `34,45` and `74,23`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you a `List<int>`.

```
str.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

If you are not sure that all strings are parsable to `int`, or your string contains multiple commas like `23,,24,25` or invalid charachters you can use `Where` to filter the sequence first:

```
var numbers = str.Split(',').Where(x => x.All(char.IsDigit)).Select(int.Parse);
```

Or you can use `TryParse`:

```
var numbers = str.Split(',').Select(x =>
        {
            int result;
            if (int.TryParse(x, out result)) return result;
            return int.MinValue;
        }).Where(x => x != int.MinValue).ToList();
```

Probably, `TryParse` is the best option because [`char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `true` for all digits, not just `(0-9)`.

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq:

```
var numbers = y.Split(',').Select(num => int.Parse(num)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you

```
string source = "34,45,74,23";
var stringArray = source.Split(',');
var intArray = stringArray.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the format is valid you can use [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [`List<T>` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is more efficient:

```
string[] numbers = "34,45,74,23".Split(',');
var list = new List<int>(Array.ConvertAll(numbers, int.Parse));
```